# VBA Run-time error 424: Object required with Word document SaveAs

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have an issue with this piece of code I'm writing. When I run the macro it gives me an "Run-time error '424': Object required" on the

```
  ActiveDocument.SaveAs filename:="C:\test\test.docx", _
FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
```

line.

I suppose this has something to do with the word Document and the word window situation, but I don't know how to solve it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! (After the mentioned line I need to close the word document as well, maybe anyone could help with that too?)

```
Dim objword As Object
Dim objDoc As Object
Dim fNameAndPath As Variant
Dim fNameAndPath2 As Variant

fNameAndPath = "C:\test"
fNameAndPath2 = "C:\test2"

i = 2
While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3)) ' or whevever you want to start
    If Cells(i, 9) = "End of Probation Per" Then
        Set objword = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        objword.Visible = True
        objword.Documents.Open (fNameAndPath)
        objword.Activate
        With objword.ActiveDocument
            .Bookmarks("EmpName").Range.Text = Cells(i, 2).Value
            .Bookmarks("EndDate").Range.Text = Cells(i, 11).Value
              ActiveDocument.SaveAs filename:="C:\test\test.docx", _
FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False    
        End With
        Else: Cells(i, 9).Font.Italic = True
    End If
    i = i + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fully qualify the object:

```
objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs filename:="C:\test\test.docx", _
FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
```

Also note that if you haven't set a reference to the Word object library, the constant `wdFormatXMLDocument` has no value, so you should define it:

```
Const wdFormatXMLDocument As Long = 12
```

Re your last comment, you can include a cell value for the file name:

```
objWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs filename:="C:\test\" & cells(i, 2).value & ".docx", _
FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument, AddToRecentFiles:=False
```

Comment: How would you name the FileFormat in this case? I just want a docx document.

Comment: Either use `FileFormat:=12` or, preferably, add a constant to the top of your code: `Const wdFormatXMLDocument As Long = 12`

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to ask another question. What would the code be in order to place a value from Cells(i,2) in the new filename so I can make a personal filename for each row? Should I work with bookmark values or rather with a value from excel?